# Delete a row based on another row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following:

```
stock   |   Customer   
12345   |   NULL
12345   |   ABC
```

What I want to do is remove the first without affecting the second anytime there is a set of rows like this:

```
 if exists (select stock   from table WHERE stock='12345' AND Customer   is not null )
            BEGIN
                DELETE FROM table WHERE stock= '12345' AND  Customer    is null
            END
```

The query works, but how can I change it so that I don't have to specify a stock? I want to keep the rows with null customer is it is the only value associated with that stock.

Comment: won't this work `where Customer    is null` for your ask :`how can I change it so that I don't have to specify a stock? `

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I want to keep the rows with null customer is it is the only value associated with that stock number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use exists:

```
DELETE t0
FROM table t0
WHERE Customer IS NULL
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM table t1
    WHERE t0.stock = t1.stock
    AND t1.Customer IS NOT NULL
)
```

This will only delete records where the customer is null and there is at least one record with the same stock id.

Comment: Your logic is reversed, you are deleting the rows with customer information

Answer (score 3):

Please check following SQL DELETE command within CTE expression
I used [SQL Count function with Partition By](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx) clause.
For testing NOT NULL customer field values I counted them per stock with filed name enabling me to remove NULL

```
;with cte as (
    select 
        stock, 
        Customer,
        cnt = Count(Customer) over (partition by stock)
    from StockCustomer
)
delete from cte 
where Customer is null and cnt > 0
```

You can consider different situations like in following rows

```
create table StockCustomer (stock   int, Customer   varchar(10))
insert into StockCustomer  select 12345   ,   NULL
insert into StockCustomer  select 12345   ,   'ABC'
insert into StockCustomer  select 11111   ,   'XYZ'
insert into StockCustomer  select 555555   ,   NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
WITH CTE (stock, customer, DuplicateCount)
AS
(
SELECT stock, customer,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Stock ORDER BY customer desc) AS DuplicateCount
FROM [Table]
)
DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1 and customer is NULL
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross join` as follows:

```
    DELETE
    FROM mytable
    WHERE stock IN (
            SELECT m2.stock
            FROM mytable m1
            CROSS JOIN mytable m2
            WHERE m1.customer IS NULL
            GROUP BY m2.stock
            HAVING count(m2.stock) > 1
            )
    AND customer is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `delete from table where customer is null` if this is your only requirement.